# Vue not creating store when building for production

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a Vue.js application which when I run "npm run serve" it will create a Vuex store seen by dev tools and will do everything the store is meant to do. However when I run a "npm run build" command then test my application it will only let parts work that don't depend on the store. Nothing in my .env file is different other than API endpoints and some (public) API keys used by the front end. Anyone know what might be the issue why a production build won't have a Vuex store? Google showed me lots of results about it not showing in dev tools but nothing on the cause of my issue

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: @DecadeMoon No errors, I have no real information to share other than what is in the post sadly - I think? I can share my .env file but I don't think that would be of help since it's just some API keys and a couple of API endpoints. Honestly pretty lost on what it might be

Comment: I just need some clarification on what you mean exactly by "store not building". Are you saying your store initialization code isn't being executed, and thus the store isn't created in production? If the store isn't created then I would expect code that interacts with the store (accessing state and firing mutations) would error. Or do you simply mean the Vue devtools extension doesn't detect it in production? Because that's the default behavior.

Comment: @DecadeMoon I mean that the dev tools don't see it and best I can tell the store is not working properly. So an example, it is a chat application which uses sockets, the socket will receive a message called "total" which should store the "total" and display it on screen. However what is happening is the socket code is being triggered but the "total" is not displaying on screen when building for prod/staging but does on npm run serve